# MC-Cordova-Plugin not working [ionic - Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

Im using this plugin for ionic:

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin

I made it work on iOS, but on android seems like the plugin doesn't even exist. I think is something about how Im calling the pluging since I am not very good at angular.

app.module.ts:

```
import { PushNotificationsService } from './../modules/somefolder/push-notifications/';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    InicioPage

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    InicioPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    PushNotificationsService,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And i have a module on my proyect:

```
-modules
 |_somefolder
  |_push-notifications
   |_interfaces
   | |_push-notifications.interface.ts
   |
   |_models
   | |_push-notifications.models.ts
   |
   |_providers
   | |_push-notifications.service.ts
   |
   |_index.ts
   |_push-notifications.module.ts
```

push-notifications.interface.ts:

```
import { Attributes } from './../';

export interface PushNotificationsInterface {

  // ANDROID AND iOS FEATURES

  // Logging
  enableVerboseLogging(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;
  disableVerboseLogging(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;

  // Push
  isPushEnabled(successCallback: (enabled: boolean) => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;

  // Get system token.
  getSystemToken(successCallback: (systemToken: string) => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;

  // Attributes
  getAttributes(successCallback: (attributes: Attributes) => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;
  setAttribute(successCallback: (success: boolean) => void, errorCallback: () => void, key: string, value: string): void;
  clearAttribute(successCallback: (attributeRemoved: string) => void, errorCallback: () => void, key: string): void;

  // ContactKey           
  setContactKey(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void, contactKey: string): void;
  getContactKey(successCallback: (contactKey: string) => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;

  // Tags           
  addTag(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void, tag: string): void;
  removeTag(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void, tag: string): void;
  getTags(successCallback: (tags: Array<string>) => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;

  // ANDROID ONLY FEAURES

  // Push

  enablePush(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;
  disablePush(successCallback: () => void, errorCallback: () => void): void;

}
```

push-notifications.models.ts:

```
export interface Attributes {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

push-notifications.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PushNotificationsInterface } from './../';
import { Attributes } from './../';

declare const MCCordovaPlugin: PushNotificationsInterface;

@Injectable()
export class PushNotificationsService {

  // ANDROID AND iOS FEATURES

  public isPushEnabled(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.isPushEnabled(
        (enabled: boolean) => resolve(enabled),
        () => reject('Can Not Determinate If Is Enabled')
      );
    });
  }

  public getContactKey(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.getContactKey(
        (key: string) => resolve(key),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Get Contact Key'))
      );
    });
  }

  public setContactKey(contactKey: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.setContactKey(
        () => resolve(true),
        () => reject('Can Not Set Contact Key'),
        contactKey
      );
    });
  }

  public getSystemToken(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.getSystemToken(
        (systemToken: string) => resolve(systemToken),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Get System Token'))
      );
    });
  }

  public getAttributes(): Promise<Attributes> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.getAttributes(
        (attributes: Attributes) => resolve(attributes),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Get Attributes'))
      );
    });
  }

  public setAttribute(key: string, value: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.setAttribute(
        (success: boolean) => resolve(success),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Set Attribute')),
        key, value
      );
    });
  }

  public clearAttribute(attribute: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.clearAttribute(
        (attributeRemoved: string) => resolve(attributeRemoved),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Remove Attribute')),
        attribute
      );
    });
  }

  public getTags(): Promise<Array<string>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.getTags(
        (tags: Array<string>) => resolve(tags),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Get Tags'))
      );
    });
  }

  public addTag(tag: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.addTag(
        () => resolve(),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Add Tag')),
        tag
      );
    });
  }

  public removeTag(tag: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.removeTag(
        () => resolve(),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Remove Tag')),
        tag
      );
    });
  }

  // ANDROID ONLY FEAURES

  public enablePush(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.enablePush(
        () => resolve(),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Remove Tag'))
      );
    });
  }

  public disablePush(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MCCordovaPlugin.disablePush(
        () => resolve(),
        () => reject(new Error('Can Not Remove Tag'))
      );
    });
  }

}
```

index.ts:

```
export { PushNotificationsInterface } from './interfaces/push-notifications.interface';
export { Attributes } from './models/push-notifications.models';
export { PushNotificationsService } from './providers/push-notifications.service';
export { PushNotificationsModule } from './push-notifications.module';
```

push-notifications.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { PushNotificationsService } from "./";

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    PushNotificationsService
  ]
})
export class PushNotificationsModule {}
```

And finally my ionic page where i call the plugin:

```
import { IonicPage, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Attributes, PushNotificationsService  } from './../../modules/cloud-mobile/push-notifications';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-inicio',
  templateUrl: 'inicio.html',
})
export class InicioPage{

  public pushEnabled: boolean;
  public contactKey: string;
  public systemToken: string;
  public attributes: Array<{$key: string, value: string}>;
  public tags: Array<string>;

  constructor(private pushNotifications: PushNotificationsService, public platform: Platform) {
    this.iniciarPushNotifications();
  }

  iniciarPushNotifications(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.isPushEnabled();
      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      if (user) {
        this.setContactKey(user.email);
        this.getSettings();
      } 
    });
  }


  private getSettings(): void {
    this.getContactKey();
    this.getSystemToken();
    this.getAttributes();
    this.getTags();
  }

  // START MCCordovaPlugin Methods

  private isPushEnabled() {
    this.pushNotifications.isPushEnabled()
      .then((enabled: boolean) => {
        console.log('Push enabled ->' + enabled);
        alert('Push enabled ->' + enabled);
        this.pushEnabled = enabled
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  private getContactKey(): void {
    this.pushNotifications.getContactKey()
      .then((key: string) => {
        alert(key);
        this.contactKey = key
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  public setContactKey(ccontactKey): void {  
    this.pushNotifications.setContactKey(ccontactKey)
      .then((success: boolean) => {
          if(success) {
            this.getSettings();
          } else {
            console.log('No se pudo asignar el Contact Key');
          }
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  private getSystemToken(): void {
    this.pushNotifications.getSystemToken()
      .then((systemToken: string) => {
        alert(systemToken);
        this.systemToken = systemToken
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  private getAttributes(): void {
    this.attributes = new Array<{$key: string, value: string}>();
    this.pushNotifications.getAttributes()
      .then((attributes: Attributes) => {
        Object.keys(attributes).map((key: string) => this.attributes.push({
          $key: key,
          value: attributes[key]
        }));
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  public setAttribute(inputKey: any, inputValue: any): void {
    if(inputKey.value && inputValue.value && !this.attributes.find((attribute: {$key: string, value: string}) => 
      attribute.$key == inputKey.value
    )) {
      this.pushNotifications.setAttribute(inputKey.value, inputValue.value)
        .then((success: boolean) => {
          if(success) {
            inputKey.value = '';
            inputValue.value = '';
            this.getAttributes();
          }
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
    }
  }

  public clearAttribute(attrKey: string) {
    this.pushNotifications.clearAttribute(attrKey)
      .then((attributeRemoved: string) => console.log(attributeRemoved))
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  private getTags(): void {
    this.tags = new Array<string>();
    this.pushNotifications.getTags()
      .then((tags: Array<string>) => {
        this.tags = tags;
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  public addTag(inputTag: any): void {
    if(!this.tags.find((tag: string) => tag == inputTag.value) && inputTag.value != '') {
      this.pushNotifications.addTag(inputTag.value)
        .then(() => {
          inputTag.value = '';
          this.getTags();
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
    }
  }

  public removeTag(tag: string): void {
    this.pushNotifications.removeTag(tag)
      .then(() => console.log(`Tag ${tag} Removed`))
      .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error.message));
  }

  // END MCCordovaPlugin Methods

}
```

So... on ios it works, on android dont.

On android the "system.log()", "alert()" doesn't even show, no errors, anything, i have been trying everithing like for 3 weeks now, im clueless at this point, please help, any ideas?

Thank you guys, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thank you for the downvotes haha, i finally fixed it, if someone is dealing with this, here is the solution:

I had my android build with:

- cordova 8.0.0
- cordova-android 7.0.0

(see yours with command: ionic info)

So apparently something is broken with that version and MC-Cordova-plugin.

Solution:
Downgrade cordova version:

1. ionic cordova platform rm android
2. npm uninstall -g cordova
3. npm install -g cordova@7.0.0
4. ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
5. ionic cordova build android
6. ionic cordova run android

Done!